# Converting something to bytes

Tags: arrays, go, type-conversion, byte

I want to convert a variable (I took an int for this example) to a byte using this code that I have found:

```
func IntToByteArray(num int64) []byte {
    size := int(unsafe.Sizeof(num))
    arr := make([]byte, size)
    for i := 0 ; i < size ; i++ {
        byt := *(*uint32)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&num)) + uintptr(i)))
        arr[i] = byte(byt)
    }
    return arr
}

func main(){
    println(IntToByteArray(1456))
}
```

But the output that it gives me is this one : [8/8]0xc00001a0d0
Can some one explain me why do I have this has a result?
And what is exactly a byte array?

Comment: That's not a byte array, that's a byte slice. If you want to know what arrays, slices, and other language fundamentals are and do, please take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/)

Comment: Use `fmt.Println(IntToByteArray(1456))` to get the printed result that you expect.  The `println`  output for a slice is not specified.

Comment: For the general case, use functions in encoding/binary.

Comment: And never use package unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func IntToByteArray(num int64) []byte {
    r := make([]byte, 8)
    for i := 0; i < len(r); i++ {
        r[i] = byte(num >> (i * 8) & 255)
    }

    return r
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(IntToByteArray(65280))
}
```

This assumes little-endianness.

As others have suggested, the included packages are more flexible and tested.